# Android app to capture system sounds?

Tags: android, audio

I want to record only the system sound of my tablet. Is there an app that does that?

Requirements:

- Runs on Android version 4.4.2 for Samsung Galaxy Tab 3
- Only captures the systems sounds and alerts (and not the microphone input)

Comment: Hi Josh. I have reworded your question to try and make it clearer, but it could still use some more specifications (desired output format, possibly also an example use-case). Please check [this FAQ](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/6834) on `What is required for a question to contain enough information`.

Comment: Will be a tough one in any case. While researching for my list of [audio recorders](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_audiorec), I didn't see anything related. Ping me back if I missed it...